# .loc data frame causes value Error Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Tags: python, pandas

This .loc syntax is how i usually set Values at certain rows, but in this case it returns this error: ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer. .notnull works as expected, i don't understand why it even touches rows where M is np.nan.

Expected Output: Change MN value in rows with M not Null to 01.01.2019

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

example = {'M': [2020,2020,2020,np.nan],
        'MN': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(example, columns = ['M', 'MN'])

print(df.loc[df['M'].notnull()])

df.loc[df['M'].notnull(),'MN'] = pd.to_datetime('01.01.' +(df['M'].astype('int32') -1).astype(str),format='%d.%m.%Y')

print(df)
```

Shouldn't it just use all the rows where M is not np.nan?
Is this syntax not "by the book"? What should i use instead?

Comment: can you please show a part of the df your using that logic as well as the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm..im not sure why but here is a work around

`df.loc[df['M'].notnull(), 'MN'] = pd.to_datetime('01.01.'+(df['M'].dropna().astype(int)-1).astype(str), format='%d.%m.%Y')`

```
        M                   MN
0  2020.0  2019-01-01 00:00:00
1  2020.0  2019-01-01 00:00:00
2  2020.0  2019-01-01 00:00:00
3     NaN                  NaN
```

One guess would be, when calling `pd.to_datetime` pandas pulls from the original df instead of the sliced one.

In other workds pandas computes the operation then slices based on the loc. This explanation makes sense since
`df.loc[df['M'].notnull(), 'MN'] = df['M']`
works as expected